# Когда инициализируется эн-ая по счету переменная то перестает работь программа

Tags: c++

у меня творится что то непонятное.

когда я инициализирую переменную все престает работать.

Это я начал делать "консольное меню". До этого весь функционал прописал просто подряд, все было хорошо. Потом начал делать меню, через while и switch. И все хорошо шло и работало, пока не дошел вот до такой проблемы...

Код также добавил, в самом конце в main в case 3

[image: Вот так работает]

[image: Программа запускаться]

[image: А вот так уже не запускается..]

[image: не работает]

[image: вот так выглядел кусок из последовательной программы]

```html
#include <iostream> 
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


#define MAX_SUBJECTS 10
#define MAX_STR 256

#define VALID_SUBJ(subjectID) (subjectID >= 0 && subjectID <= MAX_SUBJECTS - 1)
#define VALID_GRADE(grade) (grade >= 0 && grade <= 5)

/*

    Иерархия: 
    University - контейнер композитный
    Object -> Human -> Student
                      \      
                        > Teacher -> HeadTeacher
                                   \
                                    -> Research

*/

//Базовый класс
class Object
{
public:
    
    //обязательно деструктор должен быть виртуальным!
    virtual ~Object() { cout << "dtor Object" << endl; }
        
    virtual void printAbout() const = 0; //теперь класс Object считается виртуальным, его экземпляры создавать нельзя   
};

class Student; class Teacher;
// Родительский класс
class Human: public Object
{
    char fio[MAX_STR];
    int yearBirth;
    int basicPay = 5000;
    static int nextId;
    int numb_id;
protected:
    int type;

    
    
public:
    
    Human(const char* fio, int yearBirth): yearBirth(yearBirth)
    {
        numb_id = nextId++;
        strcpy(this->fio, fio);
    }
    
    Human(const char* fio)
    {
        strcpy(this->fio, fio? fio : "нет имени");
        yearBirth = 0;
    }
    
    ~Human() { cout << "dtor Human" << endl; }
    
    const char* getFIO() const { return fio; }
    
    int getBasicPay() const { return basicPay; }
    
    int getId() const {return numb_id;}
    
    int getTypeHuman() const { return type; }
    
    int getYearBT() const
    {
        
        return yearBirth;
    }
    
    int getAge() const
    {
        time_t t = time(NULL);
        return (localtime(&t)->tm_year + 1900) - yearBirth;
    }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        //cout << "Human::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        //Object::printAbout(); // можно вызвать реализацию по-умолчанию если она определена
        cout << getFIO() << " " << getAge() << " лет." << endl;
    }
    

    
    virtual void printAboutMiniens() {return;}
    
    virtual float getFullPay() const { return 0;}
    
    virtual void addMinien(Human* newMinien) { return; }
    
    virtual void setValue(int subjectId, int value) { return; }
    
    //virtual void setGrade(int subjectId, int grade) { return; }
    
    virtual int geValue(int subjectId) const { return 0; }
    
};

int Human::nextId = 1;

// Класс - потомок 1
class Student: public Human
{
    int grades[MAX_SUBJECTS];

    
    void printGrades() const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет №" << i + 1 << ": ";
            
            if( grades[i] )
                cout << " оценка " << grades[i];    
            else
                cout << "нет оценки";   
                
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    
public:
    
    Student(const char* fio, int yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        type = 1;
        memset(&grades, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    
    void setValue(int subjectId, int value)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId) || !VALID_GRADE(value)) return;
        
        grades[subjectId] = value;
    }
    
    /*int getValue(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        
        return grades[subjectId];
    }*/

    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        float k;
        int countMarks[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            switch (grades[i])
            {
                case 1: {countMarks[0] += 1; break;}
                case 2: {countMarks[1] += 1; break;}
                case 3: {countMarks[2] += 1; break;}
                case 4: {countMarks[3] += 1; break;}
                case 5: {countMarks[4] += 1; break;}
            }
        }
        if (countMarks[1] > 0) {k = 0.0;}
        else if (countMarks[2] > 0) {k = 0.5;}
        else if (countMarks[3] > 0) {k = 1;}
        else if (countMarks[4] > 0) {k = 1.5;}
        return getBasicPay() * k;
     
     }
    
    /*virtual*/ void printAbout() const override
    {
        //cout << "Student::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << "Информация о студенте: ";
        Human::printAbout(); cout << "Выплачевыемые денежные средства: " << getFullPay() << endl;
        printGrades(); cout << endl;
    }
};


// Класс - потомок 2
class Teacher: public Human
{
    int subjects[MAX_SUBJECTS];
    
protected:
    void printSubjects() const
    {
        cout << "Ведет предметы:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Предмет № " << i + 1 << ": ";
            if(subjects[i]) 
                cout << "Часов: " << subjects[i];
            else
                cout << "Не ведет.";    
            cout << endl;
        }
    }   
        
public:
    
    Teacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Human(fio, yearBirth), subjects{}
    {
        type = 2;
        //memset(&subjects, 0, MAX_SUBJECTS * sizeof(int));
    }
    
    virtual ~Teacher() { cout << "dtor Teacher" << endl; }
    
    void setValue(int subjectId, int subjectHour)
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return;
        subjects[subjectId] = subjectHour;
    }
    
    int getSubject(int subjectId) const
    {
        if(!VALID_SUBJ(subjectId)) return 0;
        return subjects[subjectId];
    }
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        int sumHour = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBJECTS; ++i)
        {
            if(subjects[i]) { sumHour += subjects[i];}
        }
        return getBasicPay() * sumHour / 60;
     
     }
    
    /*virtual*/ void printAbout() const override
    {
        //cout << "Teacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << "Информация о преподавателе: ";
        Human::printAbout(); cout << "Выплачевыемые денежные средства: " << getFullPay() << endl;
        printSubjects(); cout << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void printAboutStuds() {return;}
    
};


class HeadTeacher: public Teacher
{       
    Human** zams;
    int zamsCount;
    int zamsCapacity;
    
    void alloc(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <= zamsCapacity) return;
        
        //выделяем массив указателей!
        Human** zamsExtend = new Human*[capacity];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < zamsCount; ++i)
            zamsExtend[i] = zams[i];
            
        //не забываем удалить старый массив, т.к. он уже не нужен
        if(zamsCount) 
            delete[] zams;
            
        zams = zamsExtend;  
        
        zamsCapacity = capacity;
    }

    public:
    
    
    HeadTeacher(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        type = 3;
        zamsCapacity = 0;
        zamsCount = 0;
        alloc(5);
    }
    
    HeadTeacher(const HeadTeacher& other) = delete;
    HeadTeacher& operator=(const HeadTeacher& other) = delete;
    
    virtual ~HeadTeacher()
    {
        cout << "dtor HeadTeacher" << endl;
        if(zamsCapacity)
            delete[] zams;
    }
    
    void addMinien(Human* newMinien)
    {
        if (newMinien->getTypeHuman() == 2)
        {
            if(zamsCount == zamsCapacity) 
            alloc(zamsCapacity * 2); //всегда увеличиваем массив в 2 раза
            zams[zamsCount++] = newMinien;
        }
        else { cout << newMinien->getFIO() << " - Не преподаватель!" << endl;}
        
    }
    
    void printAboutMiniens()
    {
        cout << "Заместители " << zamsCount << " штук:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < zamsCount; ++i)
            cout << "Преподаватель: " << zams[i]->getFIO() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }   
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        return Teacher::getFullPay() * 1.6;
        
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        //cout << "HeadTeacher::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << "Информация о заведующем: ";
        Human::printAbout(); cout << "Выплачевыемые денежные средства: " << getFullPay() << endl;
        Teacher::printSubjects(); cout << endl;
    }
    
};



class Research: public Teacher
{       
    Human** studs;
    int studsCount;
    int studsCapacity;
    
    void alloc(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <= studsCapacity) return;

        Human** studsExtend = new Human*[capacity];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < studsCount; ++i)
            studsExtend[i] = studs[i];
            
        //не забываем удалить старый массив, т.к. он уже не нужен
        if(studsCount) 
            delete[] studs;
            
        studs = studsExtend;    
        
        studsCapacity = capacity;
    }

    public:
    
    
    Research(const char* fio, unsigned short yearBirth) : Teacher(fio, yearBirth)
    {
        type = 4;
        studsCapacity = 0;
        studsCount = 0;
        alloc(5);
    }
    
    Research(const Research& other) = delete;
    Research& operator=(const Research& other) = delete;
    
    virtual ~Research()
    {
        cout << "dtor Research" << endl;
        if(studsCapacity)
            delete[] studs;
    }
    
    void addMinien(Human* newMinien) 
    {
        if (newMinien->getTypeHuman() == 1)
        {
            if(studsCount == studsCapacity) 
            alloc(studsCapacity * 2); //всегда увеличиваем массив в 2 раза
            studs[studsCount++] = newMinien;
        }   
        else { cout << newMinien->getFIO() << " - Не студент!" << endl;}
    }
    
    void printAboutMiniens()
    {
        cout << "Студенты практиканты " << studsCount << " штук:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < studsCount; ++i)
            cout << "Студент: " << studs[i]->getFIO() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }   
    
    float getFullPay() const 
    {
        return Teacher::getFullPay() * 0.05;
        
     }
    
    virtual void printAbout() const override
    {
        //cout << "Research::printAbout(...)" << endl;
        cout << "Информация о научном сотруднике: ";
        Human::printAbout();
        cout << "Выплачевыемые денежные средства: " << getFullPay() << endl;
        Teacher::printSubjects(); cout << endl;
        
    }
    
};


class University
{
    Human** faculty;
    int facultyCount; //количество используемых элементов в массиве Department
    int facultyCapacity = 0; //ёмкость динамического массива, всегда больше или равна facultyCount
    
    void alloc(int capacity)
    {
        if(capacity <= facultyCapacity) return;
        Human** facultyExtend = new Human*[capacity];   
        for(int i = 0; i < facultyCount; ++i) facultyExtend[i] = faculty[i];
        if(facultyCapacity) 
            delete[] faculty;
        faculty = facultyExtend;    
        facultyCapacity = capacity;
    }
    
    public:
    
    University()
    {
        facultyCount = 0;
        alloc(10); // хотим увидет как расширяется массив, в реальном случае стоит конечно брать большее значение
    }
    
    // удаляем конструктор копии и оператор присваивания
    // т.к. иначе нам придётся их переопределять (ведь мы используем динамическую память)
    University(const University& other) = delete;
    University& operator=(const University& other) = delete;
    
    ~University()
    {
        if(facultyCapacity)
            delete[] faculty;
    }
    
    /*
    type = 1,2,3,4
    1 - Студент, 2 - Преподаватель, 3 - HeadTeacher, 4 - Reseacrh
    */
    void addHumans(const char* fio, int yearBirth, int type)
    {
        if(facultyCount == facultyCapacity) 
            alloc(facultyCapacity * 2); //всегда увеличиваем массив в 2 раза
        Human* Obj;
        //cout << type << endl;
        if(type == 1) faculty[facultyCount] = new Student(fio, yearBirth);
        if(type == 2) faculty[facultyCount] = new Teacher(fio, yearBirth);
        if(type == 3) faculty[facultyCount] = new HeadTeacher(fio, yearBirth);
        if(type == 4) faculty[facultyCount] = new Research(fio, yearBirth);
        facultyCount += 1;
    }
    

    
    void removeHumans(int id)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < facultyCount; ++i)
        {
            if(id == faculty[i]->getId()) // нашли совпадение имени
            {
                //просто сдвигаем все элементы влево, затирая удаляемый элемент
                //здесь опять вызывается оператор присваивания = по-умолчанию для Department!
                delete faculty[i];
                for(int j = i + 1; j < facultyCount; ++j)
                    faculty[j - 1] = faculty[j];
                
                --facultyCount;
                return;
            }
        }
        cout << "Неудалось удалить найти сущность с таким ID..." << endl;   
    }
    
    Human* getHumans(int i) { return faculty[i]; }
    
    int getFacultyCount() {return facultyCount; }
    
    void printAboutHuman(int k)
    {
        string tName;
        cout << "Университет состоит из " << facultyCount << " личностей:" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < facultyCount; ++i)
        {
            if(faculty[i]->getTypeHuman() == 1) tName = " Студент.";
            else if(faculty[i]->getTypeHuman() == 2) tName = " Преподаватель.";
            else if(faculty[i]->getTypeHuman() == 3) tName = " Заведующий.";
            else if(faculty[i]->getTypeHuman() == 4) tName = " Научный работник.";
            cout << faculty[i]->getId() << ") " << faculty[i]->getFIO() << " " << faculty[i]->getAge() << " лет."<< tName << endl;
            if (k == 1)
            {
                faculty[i]->printAbout();
                faculty[i]->printAboutMiniens();
            }
        }
            
        
        //cout<< "[Отладка] Ёмкость массива до " << facultyCapacity << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    
    
    
};



void printAboutObject(const Object* object)
{
    object->printAbout();
}

int random(int min, int max)
{
  if (max < min) {swap(min, max);}
  return min + rand() % (1 + max - min);
}

void PeremeshivanieMassiva(int m[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    std::swap(m[i], m[std::rand() % size]);
}

void zeroArr(int a[], int size)
{
    memset(a, 0, size*sizeof(int));
}


int maxArrayIndex(int length, int *arr)
{
    int max = arr[0];
    int max_i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max) 
        {
            max = arr[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }
    return max_i;
}

int minArrayIndex(int length, int *arr)
{
    int min = arr[0];
    int min_i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
            min_i = i;
        }
    }
    return min_i;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    srand(time(0));
    string names[10] = { "Дмитрий", "Андрей", "Илья", "Антон", "Глеб", "Даниил", "Ярослав", "Максим", "Григорий", "Владимир" };
    string surnames[10] = { "Калашников", "Самойлов", "Куликов", "Семенов", "Зуев", "Серов", "Шмелев", "Кулешов", "Дубов", "Винокуров" };
    int N, year, tp, sw;
    int id_type1[N], id_type2[N], id_type3[N], id_type4[N];
    int k1=0, k2=0, k3=0, k4=0;  
    bool f = true;
    University univer;
    cout << "Введите желаемое количество будующих сущностей. N: ";
    cin >> N; cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        tp = random(1, 4);
        switch (tp)
            {
                case 1: {year = random(1999, 2005); id_type1[k1++] = i; break;}
                case 2: {year = random(1950, 1995); id_type2[k2++] = i; break;}
                case 3: {year = random(1950, 1990); id_type3[k3++] = i; break;}
                case 4: {year = random(1980, 1997); id_type4[k4++] = i; break;}             
            }
        const char* fio = (names[rand() % 10] + " " + surnames[rand() % 10]).c_str();
        //cout << k1 << endl;
        univer.addHumans(fio, year, tp);
    }
            
    for(int j = 0; j < k1; ++j)
        {
            int id = id_type1[j];
            int k_subj = random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS);
            for(int k_s = 0; k_s < k_subj; ++k_s) univer.getHumans(id)->setValue(random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS), random(random(2, 4), 5));
        }
        
    for(int j = 0; j < k2; ++j)
        {
            int id = id_type2[j];
            int k_subj = random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS);
            for(int k_s = 0; k_s < k_subj; ++k_s) univer.getHumans(id)->setValue(random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS), random(80, 144) / k_subj);
        }
        
    for(int j = 0; j < k3; ++j)
        {
            int id = id_type3[j];
            int k_subj = random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS);
            for(int k_s = 0; k_s < k_subj; ++k_s) univer.getHumans(id)->setValue(random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS), random(80, 144) / k_subj);
            if (k2 > 0)
            {
                int k_zams = random(1, k2);
                PeremeshivanieMassiva(id_type2, k2);
                for(int k_z =0; k_z < k_zams; ++k_z ) univer.getHumans(id)->addMinien(univer.getHumans(id_type2[k_z]));
            }
        }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < k4; ++j)
        {
            int id = id_type4[j];
            int k_subj = random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS);
            for(int k_s = 0; k_s < k_subj; ++k_s) univer.getHumans(id)->setValue(random(1, MAX_SUBJECTS), random(80, 144) / k_subj);
            if (k1 > 0)
            {
                int k_studs = random(1, k1);
                PeremeshivanieMassiva(id_type1, k1);
                for(int k_s =0; k_s < k_studs; ++k_s ) univer.getHumans(id)->addMinien(univer.getHumans(id_type1[k_s]));    
            }
        }
        
    univer.printAboutHuman(0);
    while (f)
    {
        cout << endl << "Выберите действие." << endl;
        cout << "1) Вывести полную информацию о каждой сущности." << endl;
        cout << "2) Найти сумму всех выплаченных денег." << endl;
        cout << "3) Средняя ЗП по каждому виду сущностей." << endl;
        cout << "4) Найти самую младшую и старшую сущность в каждом виде." << endl;
        cout << "5) Удалить сущность." << endl;
        cout << "6) Выход." << endl;
        cout << "Ваш выбор... ";
        cin >> sw;
        cout << endl;
        switch (sw)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    univer.printAboutHuman(1);
                    break;
                }
            
            case 2:
                {
                    float sMoney = 0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < univer.getFacultyCount(); ++i) sMoney += univer.getHumans(i)->getFullPay();
                    cout << "Всего выплачено: " << sMoney << endl;
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    //id_type1[N], id_type2[N], id_type3[N], id_type4[N];
                    zeroArr(id_type1, N); zeroArr(id_type2, N); zeroArr(id_type3, N); zeroArr(id_type4, N); 
                    k1=0, k2=0, k3=0, k4=0;  
                    float sM1=0;
                    float sM2=0;
                    //float sM3=0;
                    //float sM4=0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < univer.getFacultyCount(); ++i)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    break;
                }
            
            
            
            case 6:
                {
                    cout << "Работа программы завершена." << endl;
                    f = false;
                    int NM = univer.getFacultyCount();
                    for (int i=0; i < NM; ++i) univer.removeHumans(i+1); 
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, где-то неверная работа с памятью. В совершенно другом месте. Так что нужен минимальный компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий ошибку... И — текстом, не картинками!

Comment: @Harry да я чукча, в самом начале main задаю массивы N размера, когда N не определена... Мне явно пора сделать перерыв

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум!

```
int N, year, tp, sw;
int id_type1[N], id_type2[N], id_type3[N], id_type4[N];
```

Опустим, что это — нестандарт, и в С++ нельзя определять массивы с размером, который выясняется только во время работы. Но! **Какой размер** у ваших массивов?

Неизвестно. Потому что в неинициализированной переменной 'N' может быть любой мусор.

UB. Дальше и рассматривать не стоит...

Comment: да, да. Я  тоже это понял. Спасибо, что уделили мне время. И всегда приходите на помощь :)